How to turn off 'Encrypted at rest' on Macbook?
I'm trying to disk imaging for my Macbook.
I booted in Target Disk Mode and imaged the disk,
but 'Macintosh hd - Data' is encrypted.
I turned off FileVault encryption, diskutil still says 'Encrypted at rest'.
How to turn off 'Encrypted at rest' on Macbook?
My Macbook is using an Intel CPU and Monterey OS.
Thank you!

All Mac’s with intel + T2 and Apple silicon encrypt the data. You can’t take that drive to another Mac and read it as the key to decrypt it is in the Secure Enclave. You can’t disable it - you can only unlock it with the key that was created when it was made.

What specifically did you do to turn off FileVault? The anti-replay feature means you lost the ability to use the old hardware based decryption key and must bring a user account password to ever unlock this data.
